# DataGridCell_Load how to know the name of the calling datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cell, parent

I want to call the same routine for different datagrids and then to switch according to the datagrid name. I tried cell.Parent. but that is always null..

```
private void DataGridCell_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
     if (cell.Column.DisplayIndex == 2 || cell.Column.DisplayIndex == 3 || cell.Column.DisplayIndex == 4)
     {
         try
         {
            double dVal = Math.Round(double.Parse(((TextBlock)cell.Content).Text),3);
            ((TextBlock)cell.Content).Text = dVal.ToString("0.00");
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("EXC");
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Use DisplayIndex carefully.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan fine you mean check before the number of columns so that I don't get an out bound index execption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <EventSetter Event="DataGridCell.Loaded" Handler="DataGridCell_Load"/>
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>



private void DataGridCell_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
            DataGrid parentGrid = (DataGrid)(cell.Tag);
        }
```

Comment: I believe setting the Tag value to actual `DataGrid` to each `DataGridCell` is not a good approach as having the collection object to each DataGrid will hit the size of application and performance.

Comment: its simple, quick and fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using `VisualTreeHelper` you can find the parent from `DataGridCell`.

```
        DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource; 
        var cell = dep as System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell;
        while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridRow))
        {
            dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
        }

        var row = dep as DataGridRow;
        if (row != null)
        {
            var dataGrid = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(row) as System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid;
            return dataGrid;
        }
```